# Filter data based on quarter of given date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The user selects a quarter of the year by clicking on one of the four radio buttons (one for each quarter) and then I must filter the data based on that quarter.  I was trying with Autofilter but I'm stuck and can't figure out what to do.

EDIT:
The snippet of code im trying to fix is this:

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value, VisibleDropDown:=False
    max = Application.max(Range("E1:E22222").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

Here, i use the Autofilter to get only the results that match the "cell.value" . After that I need to get a subset of those results based on the selected quarter. Lastly, I want to store the max value of a specific field.  What I miss is how I'm going to filter based on a specific quarter. The selected quarter is saved on the variable "selectedQuarter" as a number (ex "1" for first quarter, a result of DatePart("q", "12/22/2013")).

Comment: Post your current code.............you probably don't need AutoFilter.............just **Show/Hide** rows based upon the number of the month.....

Comment: edited the post, but the code is kinda irrelevant .

Comment: ........nothing wrong with the code..............in which column are the dates??

Comment: this code is correct and it works. It needs one more line to apply a filter on field 8 (the column with the dates) and select only the rows that are in the correct quarter of the year. 
For example 
`.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=[check if the cell contains a date in the correct quarter], VisibleDropDown:=False`
that's what i miss and i need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the criteria a string with an operator concatenated with a date, and then use the xlAnd operator, like so:

```
Private Sub AF(w As Range, selectedQuarter As Integer)

Dim c1 As String, c2 As String

Select Case selectedQuarter
  Case 1
    c1 = "1/1/2014"
    c2 = "4/1/2014"
  Case 2
    c1 = "4/1/2014"
    c2 = "7/1/2014"
  Case 3
    c1 = "7/1/2014"
    c2 = "10/1/2014"
  Case 4
    c1 = "10/1/2014"
    c2 = "1/1/2015"
End Select

w.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & c1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
                       Criteria2:="<" & c2

End Sub
```

Note, you probably already have one but you need a header field that is part of the range, and where the autofilter arrow will rest.

Comment: This is exactly what i did yesterday. Forgot to update the post. Thank you very much for your help!